# HTTP POST request from a PyQt-GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to create a simple gui with PyQt designer to send some urls to the VirusTotal service. This a simple script that can send 4 urls per minute i.e.:

```
import simplejson
import urllib
import urllib2
url = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/scan"
parameters = {"url": "http://www.virustotal.com",
...               "apikey":     "1fe0ef5feca2f84eb450bc3617f839e317b2a686af4d651a9bada77a522201b0"}
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
json = response.read()
print json
{"response_code": 1,
 "verbose_msg": "Scan request successfully queued, come back later for the report",

 "scan_id": "1db0ad7dbcec0676710ea0eaacd35d5e471d3e11944d53bcbd31f0cbd11bce31-1320752364",

 "scan_date": "2014-01-08 11:39:24",

"url": "http://www.virustotal.com/",

"permalink": "http://www.virustotal.com/url/1db0ad7dbcec0676710ea0eaacd35d5e471d3e11944d53bcbd31f0cbd11bce31/analysis/1320752364/"}
```

How can i make a gui where the user will be able to put the urls and his api key in the gui and send the request to virustotal.

I just need some guidance not a whole solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its straight forward :-

1) drag and drop the gui elements onto a widget using QtDesigner , save it . eg virustotal.ui

2) use pyuic4 to convert the ui file to a python file.(" pyuic4 virustotal.ui -o virustotal.py")

3) Then copy the above given code into the file .

4) sense for the clicked signal from a push button and assign it a slot that packages your parameter dictionary and then do as usual .

```
self.lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)    #URL
self.lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)    # API KEY
self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)   # SEND BUTTON
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton , QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()") , self.doIt)

def doIt(self):
    parameters = {"url": str(self.lineEdit1.text()),"apikey": str(self.lineEdit2.text())}
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    json = response.read()
    print json
```

This is a basic layout of how the code will run , further detailing has to done according to your needs.

Comment: Well, your answer is more than helpful, now i know how to move with PyQt, Thank you my friend.